# How to integrate my front-end in Angular with my Spring boot application?

Tags: angular, spring, war

I made an app with Spring boot and Angular,
Everything works fine but not when I try to run it from the generated war file in the target on a local application server.

I build the app I copy the angular resources from the dist directory to src/main/resources/static in my back-end.

When I run my application everything gets deployed succesfully but it doesn't seem to have access to my front-end side.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Basically, you need to deploy your angulkar app into a folder in you spring application, and then build that to get the war file. a quick search gives me http://www.jcombat.com/angular-5/deploying-spring-and-angular-application-on-the-same-server , which looks promising. How have you set it up?

Comment: I tried it and I got pretty close but I have on issue. The index.html doesn't load the scripts. They are in the same resources folder. When I look at the console it looks like the get request goes to http://localhost:8082/runtime.js instead of http://localhost:8802/myfolder/runtime.js. Why is that?